# MsysGIT не позволяет ввести пароль при push'e

Tags: git, консоль, github

Проблема в одном - моя Git Bash от [msysGit](http://msysgit.github.io/) не позволяет мне вводить пароль, когда я пушусь. Просто не реагирует на события нажатия кнопки, никак. Если же нажать enter и вводимый пароль окажется пустым, консоль мне выдаст ошибку, что мой пароль не верен, и все.

Это мой первый пуш, я изучаю гит, и вот такая проблема появилась. Ничего так и не нагуглил, буду признателен за помощь.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Это консоль? Это нормально, если при вводе пароля не происходит никаких видимых изменений. Просто введите пароль и нажмите Enter.

Comment: Вот уж эти консоли. :) Буду знать, что тип "password" вводится там именно таким образом, спасибо. :)